# c++: implementing the equal method - how to make sure the given object is not the same reference as this?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code snippet:

```
bool SomeObject::equal(const SomeObject& rhs) const
{
  if (this == &rhs)
  {
    return true;
  }

  // check the state
}
```

The problem with this code is that `SomeObject` might override `operator&` (or someone might add it in the future), which in turn may break this implementation.

Is it possible to test whether `rhs` and `*this` are the same object without being at the mercy of `operator&` implementation?

Comment: Interesting. `this==rhs.this` and `::&rhs` don't work. Good question!

Comment: @MrLister: lol at `rhs.this` :-) Shouldn't it be `std::that(rhs)`?

Comment: Actually, if you're dealing with polymorphic classes, could it be that someone passes you a base reference of `*this` and your comparison fails erroneously?

Comment: Since rhs is a real, instantiated object, why shouldn't it have `this`? As we all know, objects of the same type can access each other's private members!

Comment: There might be much larger problems if the hypothetical overloaded operator& is not usable for this purpose. Personally I wouldn't bother. - I doubt all users are going to be paranoid about the address of any library object, so introducing such an overload would wreak havoc everywhere. - I suspect that addressof is really intended for generic code that is supposed also to handle objects from libraries that are *based* on "abusing" operator overloading (such as perhaps in boost).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to get the actual address of the object and ignore overloaded `&` operators then use `std::addressof`

```
bool SomeObject::equal(const SomeObject& rhs) const
{
  if (this == std::addressof(rhs))
  {
    return true;
  }

  // check the state
}
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof

Comment: @JaredPar: Out of curiosity, how do you even discover such functions ? There is a lot of new stuff since C++11 went out, but remembering it all seems impossible to me.

Comment: Is this a C++11 feature?  If so, what's the solution where `std::addressof` isn't yet available?

Comment: @ereOn I was reading another C++ answer by KerrekSB just a few minutes ago which had this function.  I read up on it for a few minutes, refreshed stackoverflow and this question was on top. :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I guess one might just use the code given in the linked page directly: `template< class T >
T* addressof(T& arg) {
    return (T*)&(char&)arg;
}`. Which is not excessively long.

Comment: @ereOn: Ah, I didn't realise I would have to scroll down to find that.  Thanks!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes it's a C++11 feature. There is an equivalent implementation in BOOST that can be used without C++11

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You are welcome. The layout of the webpage is a bit messed up with a lot of useless spaces indeed :)

Comment: What if I specialize addressof in the future? :)

Comment: @UncleBens, the standard specifies addressof, so I'd suspect if you specialize it to do something else you are no longer standards compliant. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a `std::addressof` function in C++11 which should do what you want.

If you wanted to implement it yourself, you could use casting to another type:

```
(SomeClass*)&reinterpret_cast<char&>(rhs)
```

However, I wouldn't bother; a const `equals` function should work fine for identical parameters.

Comment: Skipping the body of the test may be a worthwhile optimization in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just removed that condition entirely?  How often is someone going to compare an object to itself?  If you usually need to inspect all the data members anyway, then this simple comparison just wastes time in the average case.  As long as nothing bad happens when the two objects are physically the same (and your function is `const`, so you should be fine), then what's the harm in doing a little extra work in the rare case?

Comment: It's critical when writing assignment operator overloads when the class is managing resources.

Comment: Yes, it's critical to gracefully handle self *assignment*, but the OP is writing `equals`.

Comment: Might be a performance gain to not have to compare all the members if you already know it's the same object.

Comment: @Kristo: Indeed.  But because of the generalisation, the OP's question is still an interesting/valid one, IMO.

Comment: @MrLister, as always, profile it and see. :-)  Unless it happens a lot, I doubt it'll matter much if at all.

Comment: @Oli, I agree, which is why I upvoted the question.  And I think this answer applies in the general case too.  No extra code to write, no libs to include, no dependence on a C++11 compiler, etc.

Comment: @MrLister - It is also a performance loss to *always* compare the addresses if they are hardly ever the same.

Answer (score -2):

Just pass a pointer to SomeObject instead of a reference, so you don't need the & operator anymore.

It would like this then:

```
bool SomeObject::equal(const SomeObject* rhs) const
{
    if ( this == rhs )
    {
         return true;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: So then you'd have to do:

SomeObject* a = ...
SomeObject* b = ...
if ((*a) == b) { ... }

Is that right? Because that seems a bit like a hack.

Comment: -1: No, because that would give horrible semantics: `if (a == &b)` (which in fact just moves the problem).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it ( it actually works for me ). If he calls the function with the adress of the object ( SomeObject* rhs) then the function it self has the pointer with the adress. This is also a pointer with the adress. If you equal them you see if they point to the same object...why is it wrong? Sorry if I seem stupid now, but then please explain it.

Comment: @Toby: When testing objects for equality, people tend to use `operator==()`. Forcing them to use a dedicated particular function which works with pointers is counter-intuitive, error prone and prevents the use of such objects in any standard algorithm which relies on `operator==()`.

Comment: @Toby: Firstly, it means the user of the class has to write something unnatural to check for equality.  Secondly, it hasn't solved the problem; if the class has an overloaded `operator &`, then that will still get called.

Comment: Ah wait, so if he implements SomeObject::equal() he overloads the == operator? Cause if so I guess I get it now..

Comment: No, it does not. But there are template based libraries (like boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/…) which implement `operator==` and others by delegating to your implementation of the `equal` method.